# Angular Momentum Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

I'm looking at a review question I was given and it quite frankly has me stumped.

"Using matrix representations find $L^{3}_{x},L^{3}_{y},L^{3}_{z}$ and from these show that $L_{x}, L_{y},L_{z}$ satisfy the same algebraic equations."

What has me stumped is the $L^{3}_{x},L^{3}_{y},L^{3}_{z}$, I'm not even sure how it makes sense to talk of the cube of L? Any pointers in the right direction here would be incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In units of $\hbar$,
$$
L_x=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0\end{bmatrix},L_y=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & i \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -i & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},L_z=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -i & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that, to compute these, I took the derivative of the [rotation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotations_in_three_dimensions) (multiplied by $i$) at $\theta =0$.  From here, it is a simple matter of computation.  For example,
$$
L_x^3=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0\end{bmatrix}=L_x
$$
Similarly, $L_y^3=L_y$ and $L_z^3=L_z$.  Thus, of course the operators $L_x^3,L_y^3,L_z^3$ obey the same commutation relations as the operators $L_x,L_y,L_z$:  they're the exact same operators!

Comment: Thanks! Looking at it now in terms of the algebra you've laid out makes sense (I should have guessed $LL^{2}=L^{3}$). I'm left wondering why I would want to use $L^{3}$ instead of $L$; for computational expediency in select situations?

Comment: @atomicpedals ". . . why would I want to use $L^3$ instead of $L$;" First of all, be careful when you write $L^3$.  $\mathbf{L}$ is a *vector*, so if you write $L^3$, I'm going to think you mean $(L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2)^{3/2}$ (because it doesn't make sense to cube a vector, although it does make sense to cube the *magnitude* of a vector), which is *not* your meaning.  As for why would you work with $L_i^3$ over $L_i$:  you wouldn't.  I'm pretty sure this exercise is just for the sake of practice.